# How to tell Druid to skip bad kafka records during ingestion with schema registry?

Tags: apache-kafka, avro, confluent-schema-registry, druid

**Long story short: Druid fails to ingest corrupted kafka record. How can I skip it?**

I configured Druid to ingest data from kafka with schema_registry successfully. Everything works as expected until Druid hits, at some offset, a bad record which doesn't have valid data because it's corrupted. If I look into task logs, I can find the following exception:

```
2022-03-14T13:46:03,647 ERROR [task-runner-0-priority-0] org.apache.druid.indexing.seekablestream.SeekableStreamIndexTaskRunner - Encountered exception while running task.
org.apache.druid.java.util.common.RE: Failed to get Avro schema: 1786271608
    at org.apache.druid.data.input.avro.SchemaRegistryBasedAvroBytesDecoder.parse(SchemaRegistryBasedAvroBytesDecoder.java:144) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.druid.data.input.avro.AvroStreamReader.intermediateRowIterator(AvroStreamReader.java:69) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.druid.data.input.IntermediateRowParsingReader.read(IntermediateRowParsingReader.java:44) ~[druid-core-0.22.1.jar:0.22.1]
    at org.apache.druid.segment.transform.TransformingInputEntityReader.read(TransformingInputEntityReader.java:43) ~[druid-processing-0.22.1.jar:0.22.1]
    at org.apache.druid.indexing.seekablestream.SettableByteEntityReader.read(SettableByteEntityReader.java:78) ~[druid-indexing-service-0.22.1.jar:0.22.1]
    at org.apache.druid.indexing.seekablestream.StreamChunkParser.parseWithInputFormat(StreamChunkParser.java:135) ~[druid-indexing-service-0.22.1.jar:0.22.1]
    at org.apache.druid.indexing.seekablestream.StreamChunkParser.parse(StreamChunkParser.java:104) ~[druid-indexing-service-0.22.1.jar:0.22.1]
    at org.apache.druid.indexing.seekablestream.SeekableStreamIndexTaskRunner.runInternal(SeekableStreamIndexTaskRunner.java:620) ~[druid-indexing-service-0.22.1.jar:0.22.1]
    at org.apache.druid.indexing.seekablestream.SeekableStreamIndexTaskRunner.run(SeekableStreamIndexTaskRunner.java:263) [druid-indexing-service-0.22.1.jar:0.22.1]
    at org.apache.druid.indexing.seekablestream.SeekableStreamIndexTask.run(SeekableStreamIndexTask.java:146) [druid-indexing-service-0.22.1.jar:0.22.1]
    at org.apache.druid.indexing.overlord.SingleTaskBackgroundRunner$SingleTaskBackgroundRunnerCallable.call(SingleTaskBackgroundRunner.java:471) [druid-indexing-service-0.22.1.jar:0.22.1]
    at org.apache.druid.indexing.overlord.SingleTaskBackgroundRunner$SingleTaskBackgroundRunnerCallable.call(SingleTaskBackgroundRunner.java:443) [druid-indexing-service-0.22.1.jar:0.22.1]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [?:1.8.0_275]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [?:1.8.0_275]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [?:1.8.0_275]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_275]
Caused by: io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.exceptions.RestClientException: Schema not found; error code: 40403
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService.sendHttpRequest(RestService.java:292) ~[?:?]
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService.httpRequest(RestService.java:351) ~[?:?]
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService.getId(RestService.java:659) ~[?:?]
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService.getId(RestService.java:641) ~[?:?]
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.CachedSchemaRegistryClient.getSchemaByIdFromRegistry(CachedSchemaRegistryClient.java:217) ~[?:?]
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.CachedSchemaRegistryClient.getSchemaBySubjectAndId(CachedSchemaRegistryClient.java:291) ~[?:?]
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.CachedSchemaRegistryClient.getSchemaById(CachedSchemaRegistryClient.java:276) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.druid.data.input.avro.SchemaRegistryBasedAvroBytesDecoder.parse(SchemaRegistryBasedAvroBytesDecoder.java:140) ~[?:?]
    ... 15 more
```

What the exception says is true, there is a record at some offsete where the bytes for the id of the schema are 1786271608, which is an invalid schema in the registry, so that throws the exception correctly. ****What I want is to skip this corrupt record and ignore it, so Druid can keep ingesting the next records. Is it possible to configure Druid that way?****

I have found in the tunning config a variable called maxParseExceptions that looks like what I'm looking for, but it is already set to a big number (2147483647, which was set by default):

> maxParseExceptions: The maximum number of parse exceptions that can occur before the task halts ingestion and fails. Overridden if reportParseExceptions is set.

Here is how my spec looks like:

```json
{
  "type": "kafka",
  "spec": {
    "dataSchema": {
      "dataSource": "my.data.source.name",
      "timestampSpec": {
        "column": "lastOperationTime",
        "format": "millis",
        "missingValue": null
      },
      "dimensionsSpec": {
        "dimensions": [     
            ... (ommited) ...           
        ],
        "dimensionExclusions": [
          "__time",
          "lastOperationTime"
        ]
      },
      "metricsSpec": [],
      "granularitySpec": {
        "type": "uniform",
        "segmentGranularity": "DAY",
        "queryGranularity": {
          "type": "none"
        },
        "rollup": false,
        "intervals": []
      },
      "transformSpec": {
        "filter": null,
        "transforms": []
      }
    },
    "ioConfig": {
      "topic": "my.topic.name",
      "inputFormat": {
        "type": "avro_stream",
        "flattenSpec": {
          "useFieldDiscovery": true,
          "fields": [
            ... (ommited) ...
          ]
        },
        "avroBytesDecoder": {
          "type": "schema_registry",
          "url": "http://schema_registry_host:port",
          "capacity": 2147483647,
          "urls": null,
          "config": null,
          "headers": null
        },
        "binaryAsString": true,
        "extractUnionsByType": false
      },
      "replicas": 1,
      "taskCount": 1,
      "taskDuration": "PT3600S",
      "consumerProperties": {
        "bootstrap.servers": "bootstrap servers ips and ports"
      },
      "pollTimeout": 100,
      "startDelay": "PT5S",
      "period": "PT30S",
      "useEarliestOffset": true,
      "completionTimeout": "PT1800S",
      "lateMessageRejectionPeriod": null,
      "earlyMessageRejectionPeriod": null,
      "lateMessageRejectionStartDateTime": null,
      "stream": "my.topic.name",
      "useEarliestSequenceNumber": true,
      "autoscalerConfig": null,
      "type": "kafka"
    },
    "tuningConfig": {
      "type": "kafka",
      "appendableIndexSpec": {
        "type": "onheap"
      },
      "maxRowsInMemory": 1000000,
      "maxBytesInMemory": 0,
      "skipBytesInMemoryOverheadCheck": false,
      "maxRowsPerSegment": 5000000,
      "maxTotalRows": null,
      "intermediatePersistPeriod": "PT10M",
      "basePersistDirectory": "/opt/druid/var/tmp/druid-realtime-persist349032434046494455",
      "maxPendingPersists": 0,
      "indexSpec": {
        "bitmap": {
          "type": "roaring",
          "compressRunOnSerialization": true
        },
        "dimensionCompression": "lz4",
        "metricCompression": "lz4",
        "longEncoding": "longs",
        "segmentLoader": null
      },
      "indexSpecForIntermediatePersists": {
        "bitmap": {
          "type": "roaring",
          "compressRunOnSerialization": true
        },
        "dimensionCompression": "lz4",
        "metricCompression": "lz4",
        "longEncoding": "longs",
        "segmentLoader": null
      },
      "reportParseExceptions": false,
      "handoffConditionTimeout": 0,
      "resetOffsetAutomatically": false,
      "segmentWriteOutMediumFactory": null,
      "workerThreads": null,
      "chatThreads": null,
      "chatRetries": 8,
      "httpTimeout": "PT10S",
      "shutdownTimeout": "PT80S",
      "offsetFetchPeriod": "PT30S",
      "intermediateHandoffPeriod": "P2147483647D",
      "logParseExceptions": true,
      "maxParseExceptions": 2147483647,
      "maxSavedParseExceptions": 10,
      "skipSequenceNumberAvailabilityCheck": false,
      "repartitionTransitionDuration": "PT120S"
    }
  }
}
```

**EDIT:**
Finally, it was a bug. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, it was a bug in druid, corrected in version 0.23.

See the full story in my post in druid forum:

https://www.druidforum.org/t/how-to-tell-druid-to-skip-bad-kafka-records-during-ingestion-with-schema-registry/7186

I would like to thank druid community for their fast response.

Answer (score 0):

ignoreInvalidRows:true try this config it should skip any rows that is not ingested by druid will be ignored as opposed to failing.

Comment: Thank you for your answer everlearner. I already set the ignore flag to true, but it was still failing. It was a bug, see my answer. However, that may help other people.